# Express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send a post request and i get this error Express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead

```
app.post("/blogs/:id/likes", isLoggedIn,function(req, res){
//lookup Campground using ID
Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
       res.redirect("/blogs");
   } else {
           //add username and id to comment
     var userIndex = blog.likes.indexOf(req.user._id);
if (userIndex > -1) {
blog.likes.splice(userIndex, 1);
} else {
blog.likes.push(req.user);
}
blog.save();


           res.redirect('/blogs/' + blog._id, {blog_id: req.params.id});


   }
});
});
```

Comment: Where is that redirect supposed to point to?

Comment: I am supposed to like the post and then redirect back to the blog post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're passing an object as second argument to `res.redirect()`, but it seems to me you want this:

```
res.redirect('/blogs/' + blog._id);
```

Comment: @robertkelp What if i need to pass the whole object ??

Comment: @AravindReddy pass it as a query string (however, make sure it doesn't contain any sensitive information, or information that shouldn't be tampered with, because query strings make that particularly easy)

Comment: @Mbanda that's not something that Express supports (or I must be looking [at the wrong documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)).

Comment: @AravindReddy . You are correct, when answering this my conscience was to `this.render()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.render) method if you want to pass something to your view which accepts `(view, locals, callback)`.

```
res.render('/blogs/' + blog._id, {blog_id: req.params.id});
```

[`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect) can only take `(status, path)`.

---

More info on [Express 5x api](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html) ⭐️

Comment: Was staring at the code wondering why it wasn't working. Was using `redirect` when I needed to use `render`.